# Typescript - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: v.toPixiPoint is not a function

Tags: typescript, extension-methods

I am trying to create some the extension toPixiPoint() for my Vector2 class but when running npm build and viewing it in the browser. I get the following error in the console.

[image]

I only get errors when I open the build in the browser. There are no errors in vs code and the function gets autocompleted. What could this mean? The weird thing is my colleague is using this exact same code in his project and it's working fine? I'm reasonably new to typescript and just can't figure it out.

**globals.d.ts**

```
import { Vector2 } from "~/ts/Physics/Vector2";
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';

declare module '~/ts/Physics/Vector2' {
    interface Vector2 {
        toPixiPoint(): PIXI.Point;
    }
}
```

**ExtensionMethods.ts**

```
import { Vector2 } from "~/ts/Physics/Vector2";
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
​
Vector2.prototype.toPixiPoint = function() : PIXI.Point {
    return new PIXI.Point(this.x, this.y);
}
```

**The call placed in the constructor of a Tank.TS**

```
let v = new Vector2(0,0);
console.log(v.toPixiPoint());
```

**TSConfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "~*": ["./*"]
    },
    "lib": ["es2015.core", "es2015.promise", "es2015.collection", "es2015.iterable", "dom"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

**Package.JSON**

```
{
    "name": "typescriptgame",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "",
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/pngjs": "^3.4.0",
        "pixi.js": "^5.2.0",
        "public": "^0.1.5",
        "strongly-typed-events": "^1.6.3",
        "typescript": "^3.7.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "parcel ./src/index.html --open",
        "build": "parcel build src/index.html --no-source-maps --public-url ./"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^12.12.17",
        "cssnano": "^4.1.10"
    }
}
```

**EDIT** 
When looking at my colleague's project, I found that he is using Babel besides Parcel. Could this have anything to do with it? He started with a setup project so he doesn't actually know why it's using Babel. I set up the project from scratch. The only big difference is that he is using Babel besides Parcel. But isn't it wierd to use two compilers? I'm researching this as we speak.

​

​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use import `"~ts/Extensions/ExtensionMethods"` in the Tank.ts. I did not think I would need that because my colleague did not use that either. But it works.